# My 2002 vw golf keeps dying?

Tags: electrical, vw, golf

Hi Just wondering if anyone can help on this subject before I give up and sell it for spares!

My VW golf (2002) had battery problems where I was going out to start the car and it would attempt to start but that was it and then the alarm would keep going off until the car was jumped. The battery was only a few months old so went back to where I got it and had it replaced.

Since then the electrics started to go, started off with the doors not locking/unlocking as usual, only some at a time but eventually they would all lock after clicking the fob several times. I then noticed less and less were working and I had to manually lock the driver door. I then noticed my mirrors wouldnt work and all the windows apart from driver.
I went out to my car the following day and turned the key.. there was nothing what so ever.. it didnt even attempt to start. A mechanic came out and connected his battery charger and my car started, battery was at first 4% but fully charged after running for a while, he took the car anyway for diagnostics. He drove it back the day after and said the battery is fine as it started the following day but my central locking/fob/windows/mirrors have gone and will cost more to fix than the car is worth. Do you think this is right? or could it be key related? if I got a new key is it likely to work?

I went out to start the car the following day, started no problems.. left it running for a while. Today I have gone out and it is  lifeless once again - not attempting to start. 
I dont know anything about cars to be honest so any help would be really really helpfull! Do you think the car has had its day and time to say goodbye?

Answer (score 1):

Your [Alternator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternator%20/) might be  broken, Its the Job of the Alternator to charge up your battery whenever you drive. This is fairly common for old vehicles"Dont worry"

In case your alternator is new but still you are facing the same issue then probably there is something wrong with your electrical system.Usually when Rats and other creatures enter a vehicle there are chances they chew a wire and short the circuit.

Simply put Go to a mechanic Ask him to check the Alternator and then ask him to check the wiring.I am 90% sure that will solve your issue and it will not cost much. If you want you can also DO it yourself    [Fixing Alternator For a VW_Golf](http://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?4483721-DIY-Replacing-an-alternator-on-your-2-0-ABA)

Answer (score 1):

You are mentioning that your windows, mirrors, and etc electrical things are not working correctly. The issue could be in your electrical wiring, sensors, relays. Also you said you tried to start it and it wouldn't start the next day after it was running fine the day before. That tells me that your alternator might not be keeping your battery charged. Could also be something in your ignition system. But probably caused by bad electrical and/or alternator malfunctions.

Answer (score 0):

It is either the alternator that has problem or there is some lights or similar that are constantly draining the battery.

If you don't know how to repair cars nor have a lot of money to fix cars, do not drive European cars. Your car do not seems to have serious problem but may cause a few thousand to fix because any small problem also costs quite a bit.

Buy a battery charger say 3-5A rating and charge overnight. if car don't go alright, then change the alternator. If car goes alright, then check draining device. I can clue you in later.